# Geonode custom development

Tags: javascript, development, geonode, django

There is not much information in the form of documentation on http://geonode.org/ development. I need to do some custom "App" development for geonode so that my users can have more functionality within the maps ie: search functions, geodesy transformations, etc.  My question is what is the recommend development path for this is it frontened (JS) or backend (django)..or something else?

Comment: you can try to work with cartoview.org it is an app market that installs on top of geonde and provide a framework to run apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the documentation there is a section on [adding django apps to geonode](http://geonode-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/devel/projects/apps.html)  In order to do this the developer install has to be performed.